# How to use sed to replace only on lines matching a regular expression?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file made of strings of the form:

```
21-11-2000
1
2
3
4
5
22-11-2000
1
2
3
4
5
```

and I would like to convert it to:

```
21-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
22-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
```

Therefore I would use sed two times. First to replace end of line with comma for every line matching `[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]` and then another sed sweep to replace every line not matching that same pattern from beginning of line to comma too.

Would there be a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{
    if ($1 ~ "^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+") {
        k=$1
        next
    }
    arr[k]=arr[k]","$1
}
END{for (a in arr) print a arr[a]}
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some `awk` variation:

```
awk -F- '{printf (NF>2?RS:",")"%s",$0}' t

21-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
22-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
```

If every record is always 6 lines, this is the best:

```
awk 'NR%6{printf "%s,",$0;next}1' t
21-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
22-11-2000,1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/-/{:a;$!N;/\n[0-9]$/s/\n/,/;ta};P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

What tools can you use? The following one-liner would work if your input file is exactly as you have described.

```
cat input | awk 1 ORS=',' | perl -pi -e 's/(\d),(\d+-|$)/$1\n$2/g'
```

Comment: Useless use of cat and useless use of -i for perl

Comment: @sputnick You could also claim `xargs` is useless because it wastes a process in order to provide convenience or clarity. Using `cat` here gives a better exposition by a clear sequence of pipelines, rather than placing input between the first and second processing steps, i.e,. A < input | B. The `-i` flag is indeed "useless" *here*, but provides a truly useful starting point to the OP to do some research on their own and find out how to automatically operate on files with Perl (and even make backup copies if they like). I expect the OP to look up every part of an answer and benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed (not only number lines)

```
sed '/-/{:a;N;/\n[^-]*$/s/\n/,/;ta};P;D' file
```